# Share a Site Collection through Powershell SharePoint 2013

Tags: powershell, permissions, site-collection, site, share

I cannot find the Powershell commands to share a site/site collection with a user or group of users. Same as Site Settings > Site Permission. Can you help me? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this PowerShell script I have created a function called AddGroupToSite, allowing you to assign a SharePoint group (must already be created in the site collection) to a site along with a permission level by specifying one line of script. This first section sets up the SPWeb object and the function:

```
$web = Get-SPWeb "http://portal"

function AddGroupToSite ($web, $groupName, $permLevel)
{
    $account = $web.SiteGroups[$groupName]
    $assignment = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPRoleAssignment($account)
    $role = $web.RoleDefinitions[$permLevel]
    $assignment.RoleDefinitionBindings.Add($role);
    $web.RoleAssignments.Add($assignment)
}
```

Once we have our function set up, we can call it and pass the relevant parameters as follows:

```
AddGroupToSite -web $web -groupName "Site Admins" -permLevel "Full Control"
AddGroupToSite -web $web -groupName "Site Readers" -permLevel "Read"
```

[Adding SharePoint groups with permission levels to sites using PowerShell](http://get-spscripts.com/2010/07/adding-groups-with-permission-levels-to.html)

[Add a SharePoint or AD group/user to all sites in a site collection using PowerShell](http://get-spscripts.com/2011/02/add-sharepoint-or-ad-groupuser-to-all.html)

Comment: Perfect! And following the second link, just changing the definition of $account in = $web.EnsureUser($groupName) shares the permission with AD groups, thank you very much!!

Comment: using `$web.SiteGroups["Site Admins"]` returns nothing for me. Also, using `$web.Sitegroups` returns an 'access is denied' error.